# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LazyBoolean

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
scala> augmentedDF1.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("database", "testdb").mode("overwrite").option("collection","e_logs").save()
```

---

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LazyBoolean
  at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
  ... 57 elided
```

- Spark version - 2.40
- Scala version - 2.11.12
- mongodb version - 4.0

Answer (score 2):

`LazyRef` is not available in Scala 2.11.12, please use Scala 12.*

Or you need to check your Mongodb spark connector to make sure it was complied in Scala 2.11.12